# Address and Address Range Syntax search memory when using windbg to do debug

Tags: debugging, search, memory, windbg

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff558855(v=vs.85).aspx
from here I know the 's ' command to search in memory, here [Address and Address Range Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff537922%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
at the buttom of the article says: "For example, 80000000 L20 specifies the range from 0x80000000 through 0x8000001F"

Could anyone help me to know why the end address is 1F? Does L20 means 20 objects?

another example: s -d 0012ff40 L20 'VUTS', here L20 means 20 count objects? what is the object size? size is determined by -d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`L`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff537922%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) refers to  the length of the range to search so using `0012ff40` as starting range, plus 32 bytes would give end address of `0012ff5f` (remember it includes the starting address).

To answer your second part the `-d` flag tells WinDbg the type of the object, in this case `DWORD` which will be [32-bit unsigned integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: See my updated answer, basically it is hex length so 32 in decimal, it is 1F becuase it also includes the starting address so this is correct.

Comment: @gfan no problem I had to reread the documentation and in particular the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff537922%28v=vs.85%29.aspx page to understand.